# Charset Encoding Issue with JavaDB and EclipseLink in JSF

Tags: jsf, encoding, eclipselink, derby, javadb

I'm new at JSF projects. What I would like my project to display UTF-8 characters correctly. When I fill an inputText with UTF-8 characters and then I press commandButton, web site doesn't display it correctly. But I can insert a word that contains utf-8 into database. I use  Apache Derby(JavaDB) and EclipseLink. How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You could encode your HTTPHeader with UTF-8 in your servlet:

```
resource.setContentType ("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Also you could put this at the top of your page:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

OR (The following within the header on your xHTML)

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And also make sure your databases are encoding UTF-8:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```